# Dapper,decimal to double? Error parsing column X

Tags: oracle, parsing, dapper

My database is Oracle. I user Dapper 1.13, which throws an exception saying `Error parsing column 3 (LATITUDE=39.2330 - Decimal)`. LATITUDE is a `double?` type in my entity.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please show us the code you are using?

Comment: @Hexie meh, that's enough information to repro it, IMO

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep, that's a bug; have fixed locally - basically, change line 2367 (wow, when did that file get so big?) from:

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, unboxType);
```

to:

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(unboxType) ?? unboxType);
```

Basically, it is emitting: `(decimal?)Convert.ChangeType(val, typeof(decimal?))` when it *should* be emitting `(decimal?)Convert.ChangeType(val, typeof(decimal))` (note the all-important `?` in the `typeof`).

**Edit**: actually, the fix that I have pushed to git is a bit more complex than just fixing the `Convert.ChangeType` - it now resolves operators as-needed, so the `decimal` <===> `double` conversions uses IL static-call.

This will be fixed in the next build. Or you can build locally. The following now passes:

```
public void TestDoubleDecimalConversions_SO18228523_RightWay()
{
    var row = connection.Query<HasDoubleDecimal>(
        "select cast(1 as float) as A, cast(2 as float) as B, cast(3 as decimal) as C, cast(4 as decimal) as D").Single();
    row.A.Equals(1.0);
    row.B.Equals(2.0);
    row.C.Equals(3.0M);
    row.D.Equals(4.0M);
}
public void TestDoubleDecimalConversions_SO18228523_WrongWay()
{
    var row = connection.Query<HasDoubleDecimal>(
        "select cast(1 as decimal) as A, cast(2 as decimal) as B, cast(3 as float) as C, cast(4 as float) as D").Single();
    row.A.Equals(1.0);
    row.B.Equals(2.0);
    row.C.Equals(3.0M);
    row.D.Equals(4.0M);
}
public void TestDoubleDecimalConversions_SO18228523_Nulls()
{
    var row = connection.Query<HasDoubleDecimal>(
        "select cast(null as decimal) as A, cast(null as decimal) as B, cast(null as float) as C, cast(null as float) as D").Single();
    row.A.Equals(0.0);
    row.B.IsNull();
    row.C.Equals(0.0M);
    row.D.IsNull();
}

class HasDoubleDecimal
{
    public double A { get; set; }
    public double? B { get; set; }
    public decimal C { get; set; }
    public decimal? D { get; set; }
}
```