# Dapper: Not able to parse floats (Error parsing column)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, dapper

I am retrieving data from SQL Server from a StoredProcedure using Dapper and I'm getting error

`Specified cast is not valid.`

and details:

`Error parsing column 4 (SubTotal=0.00 - Decimal)`

On SQL Server side the column `SubTotal` is `decimal(18, 2) NULLABLE` and on .NET side it's `decimal?`. The data being retrieved is `0.00`.

I checked this answer: [Dapper,decimal to double? Error parsing column X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228523/dapper-decimal-to-double-error-parsing-column-x)

As per answer, I replaced

`il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, unboxType);`

with

`il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(unboxType) ?? unboxType);`

on line 2360 and still getting the same error.

Anyone has any ideas about this? Thanks.

**Update**:

I tried making column non-nullable. Also tried changing column to `float` (on SQL Server) and `double` (on .NET side). None of these worked and I was getting the same error. Then I changed column to `int` and now code works fine. However, I'm working with monetary values and would like to use floating point numbers. Will investigate further...

I'm executing a stored procedure as follows

`var transaction = this.db.Query<PaymentTransactions>("usp_PaymentTransactionsGetSingleIfPaid", new { registrationId }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);`

The relevant part of the stored procedure that returns information is below.

`SELECT * FROM PaymentTransactions WHERE RegistrationId = @registrationId AND TransactionStatus = 'SUCCESS';`

**UPDATE 2**:

Dapper is working fine. Maybe there was something wrong with my dev environment. All it took was VS restart.

Comment: Can you please include the dapper sql? Are you using a stored procedure, raw sql, etc.

Comment: I updated question with code.

Comment: And how are you returning the SubTotal from the proc?

Comment: I switched to using `OUTPUT` parameters to output every column from the proc and Dapper gives me `Attempting to cast a DBNull to a non nullable type!` when cols are NULL although the columns are nullable and accepting class has nullable fields. It seems that Dapper thinks that SubTotal is `decimal` although it is defined as `decimal?`. The same happens for nullable `datetime` columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this is not Dapper specific, as I just verified the below snippet works as expected.

Try enumerating your column names explictly (instead of select *) so that the procedure returns exactly what should be mapped to `PaymentTransactions`.  Its possible there is another non-decimal column that is misnamed?

This is using Dapper v1.13 on .Net45:

Procedure:

```
create procedure dbo.Test
as
select  [SubTotal] = cast('0.01' as decimal(18,2)) 
union all 
select null;
```

Linqpad:

```
void Main()
{
    using (IDbConnection cnn = GetOpenConnection())
    {
        var users = cnn.Query<Sale>("yak.dbo.test", new { }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        users.Dump();

    }
}

public static readonly string connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=True";

public static IDbConnection GetOpenConnection()
{
  var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
  connection.Open();
  return connection;
}

public class Sale
{
   public decimal? SubTotal;
}
```

Returns:

[image]

Comment: I couldn't believe it but everything is working fine. Started VS today and everything is running fine. Did not touch the code at all. I guess it was one of those days... Thanks so much for looking into this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Don't laugh, but I had this exact same problem with Dapper in an ASP.NET MVC project and the *solution* as in the comment from @erdinger worked also for me:

- Close Visual Studio
- Start Visual Studio again

The problem was fixed this way...